Determining the General Solution of System of Two Linear Equations
I'm 1 week into Linear Algebra. So, I'm still very new to this topic. The problem is this
$$
5x - 7y  = 3 \\
-10x + 14y = -6 
$$
From high school I know that it has infinitely many solutions because they are basically the same equations just scaled differently. However, the problem asks me to find the general solution of it. We haven't covered it in class, and I would like to finish my linear algebra homework ASAP.
From scouring the internet, I was able to get that y is a free variable and x is a basic variable, and that $x = \frac{3}{5}+ \frac{7}{5}y$ and $y = y$ or we can set $y = t$ by letting t as a parameter, since i can basically set it however i want.
But, I'm not sure if I got the right answer because the solution that i got works well with the case $t= 0,1$ but not for $t=2$ because that would give me $\frac{17}{5}-14$ which is definitely not 3
Any help would be really appreciated!

You seem to forget to multiply $x$ by $5$.
Notice that the original equation says $5x-7y = 3$, if you set $y = t$, it becomes $5x - 7t = 3$. For $t = 2$, we obtain $x = \frac{17}{5}$.
Observe that $5\cdot\frac{17}{5} - 7\cdot2 = 3$.
Anyway, your general solution is correct.
Either we can have $x = \frac{3}{5} + \frac{7}{5}t$ or $y = \frac{5}{7}s + \frac{3}{7}$ where $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$.
